# ASP.NET MVC Publish Website

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET MVC website in IIS.

When I try to attach the database from the published website to SQL Server, it always attaches the ASP.NET MVC solution's database so I can't manage the roles for users on the published website's database.

For example, my solution is on drive `D:` and I copy my published website to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and add it to IIS. After that I try to attach the database from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\...\App_Data` to SQL Server but it always attaches the database from `D:\test\App_Data`

I use `File_System` to publish my website.

Comment: What does the connection string look like?

Comment: @OlaEkdahl Thanks for your replay

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;User Id =test;Password=123;Integrated Security = SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: @OlaEkdahl and i also try to use
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test.mdf;User Id =test;Password=123;Integrated Security = SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`